# JavaScript Math.floor: how guarantee number will round down?

Tags: javascript, math, floor

I want to normalize an array so that each value is

 in `[0-1)` .. i.e. "the max will never be 1 but the min can be 0."

This is not unlike the random function returning numbers in the same range.

While looking at this, I found that `.99999999999999999===1` is `true`!

Ditto `(1-Number.MIN_VALUE) === 1` But `Math.ceil(Number.MIN_VALUE)` is `1`, as it should be.

Some others: `Math.floor(.999999999999)` is `0`

 while `Math.floor(.99999999999999999)` is `1`

OK so there are rounding problems in JS.

Is there any way I can normalize a set of numbers to lie in the range `[0,1)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize"? What should be the normalized value of 1? 1.5? 2?

Comment: maybe: number/Number.MAX_VALUE

Comment: There is no "rounding problem", however there is an accuracy limit. [Javascript numbers](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) are double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 values, so after 15 digits you start to lose accuracy as there are insufficient bits to represent all numbers exactly.

Comment: The problem with your range is that it would be kind of arbitrary to what value your maximum number should be transformed. To 0.999? To 0.9999? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks all .. very good answers.  I'll submit another much more precise question later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help to examine the steps that JavaScript performs of each of your expressions.

In `.99999999999999999===1`:

1. The source text `.99999999999999999` is converted to a Number. The closest Number is 1, so that is the result. (The next closest Number is 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875, which is 1–2<sup>–53</sup>.)
2. Then 1 is compared to 1. The result is true.

In `(1-Number.MIN_VALUE) === 1`:

1. `Number.MIN_VALUE` is 2<sup>–1074</sup>, about 5e–304.
2. 1–2<sup>–1074</sup> is extremely close to one. The exact value cannot be represented as a Number, so the nearest value is used. Again, the nearest value is 1.
3. Then 1 is compared to 1. The result is true.

In `Math.ceil(Number.MIN_VALUE)`:

1. `Number.MIN_VALUE` is 2<sup>–1074</sup>, about 5e–304.
2. The ceiling function of that value is 1.

In `Math.floor(.999999999999)`:

1. The source text `.999999999999` is converted to a Number. The closest Number is 0.99999999999900002212172012150404043495655059814453125, so that is the result.
2. The floor function of that value is 0.

In `Math.floor(.99999999999999999)`:

1. The source text `.99999999999999999` is converted to a Number. The closest Number is 1, so that is the result.
2. The floor function of 1 is 1.

There are only two surprising things here, at most. One is that the numerals in the source text are converted to internal Number values. But this should not be surprising. Of course text has to be converted to internal representations of numbers, and the Number type cannot perfectly store all the infinitely many numbers. So it has to round. And of course numbers very near 1 round to 1.

The other possibly surprising thing is that `1-Number.MIN_VALUE` is 1. But this is actually the same issue: The exact result is not representable, but it is very near 1, so 1 is used.

The `Math.floor` function works correctly. It never introduces any error, and you do not have to do anything to guarantee that it will round down. It always does.

However, since you want to normalize numbers, it seems likely you are going to divide numbers at some point. When you divide, there may be rounding problems, because many results of division are not exactly representable, so they must be rounded.

However, that is a separate problem, and you have not given enough information in this question to address the specific calculations you plan to do. You should open a separate question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand one thing: this...

```
.999999999999999999
```

... is just a Number *literal*. Just as

```
.999999999999999998
.999999999999999997
.999999999999999996
...
```

... you see the pattern.

How JavaScript treats these literals is completely another story. And yes, this treatment is limited by the number of bits that can be used to store a Number *value*.

The number of possible floating point literals is infinite by definition - no matter how small is the range set for them. For example, take the ones shown above: how many of `numbers very close to 1` you may express? Right, it's infinite: just keep appending `9` to the line.

But the container for each `Number` value is quite finite: it has 64 bits. That means, it can store 2^64 different values (`Infinite`, `-Infinite` and `NaN` among them) - and that's all.

You want to work with such literals anyway? Use Strings to store them, not Numbers - and some BigMath JS library ([take your pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/is-there-a-good-javascript-bigdecimal-library)) to work with those values - as Strings, again.

But from your question it looks like you're not, as you talked about array of `Numbers` - Number *values*, that is. And in no way there can be `.999999999999999999` stored there, as there is no such Number *value* in JavaScript.

Comment: You nailed it - sometimes people confuse actual objects with their representations.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will treat any number between 0.999999999999999994 and 1 as 1, so just subtract .000000000000000006.

Of course that's not as easy as it sounds, since .000000000000000006 is evaluated as 0 in Javascript, so you could do something like:

```
function trueFloor(x)
{
    x = x * 100;
    if(x > .0000000000000006)
        x = x - .0000000000000006;
    x = Math.floor(x/100);
    return x;
}
```

**EDIT:** Or at least you'd think you could. Apparently JS casts .99999999999999999 to 1 before passing it to a function, so you'd have to try something like:

```
trueFloor("0.99999999999999999")

function trueFloor(str)
{
    x=str.substring(0,9) + 0;
    return Math.floor(x); //=> 0
}
```

Not sure why you'd need that level of precision, but in theory, I guess it works. You can see a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maC6x/)

As long as you cast your insanely precise `float` as a `string`, that's probably your best bet.

Comment: Is this standard?  Or does it vary from browser/JS implementation to another?  Thanks!

Comment: It's standard for Chrome, IE, and FF implementations. Feel free to test the fiddle in other environments if you're curious.

Comment: Note: To see the actual "standard" check out the [ECMAScript Standards Page - Section 8.5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) defining the `number` variable type. Precision is generally limited by the formula `S x M x 2^E` where E is greater than or equal to -1074

Comment: Jason: thanks!  Very interesting, and just a bit, er, odd!  But definitely good reading.  Also shows the Math.pow is slightly off .. I calculated a few of the example numbers.